# How to Sort shortcuts in a folder?

Tags: home-screen

I have made many folders on home screen on froyo containing shortcuts of applications.

Is there any way  I can sort those shortcuts by names?

Answer (score 1):

Like all things in android, there are apps to do what the os was not equipped with. In my case I use a handy little app called simi folder widget. It allows alphabetical sorting of apps along with many other options.

Comment: Is there any app to sort default folders?